# get filename from url path in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I would like to extract filename from url in R. For now I do it as follows, but maybe it can be done shorter like in python. assuming path is just string.

```
path="http://www.exanple.com/foo/bar/fooXbar.xls"
```

in R:

```
tail(strsplit(path,"[/]")[[1]],1)
```

in Python:

```
path.split("/")[-1:]
```

Maybe some sub, gsub solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a function for that...

```
basename(path)
[1] "fooXbar.xls"
```

Comment: @Justin it just so happens I'm knee deep in `file.info` , `dir.create` and friends at this precise moment!

Comment: This is really useful for something I'm working on right now!

Answer (score 1):

@SimonO101 has the most  robust answer IMO, but some other options:

Since regular expressions are greedy, you can use that to your advantage

```
sub('.*/', '', path)
# [1] "fooXbar.xls"
```

Also, you shouldn't need the `[]` around the `/` in your `strsplit`.

```
> tail(strsplit(path,"/")[[1]],1)
[1] "fooXbar.xls"
```